# mpiexec - error connecting to the Service

Tags: c++, mpi

I`d like to analyze a mpi-programme using Intel trace analyzer and collector. I do the following steps:
1) mpiicc -trace first.cpp second.cpp -o prog
2) mpiexec -n 3 prog.exe
After step 2 I get an error:

```
Error connecting to the Service
[mpiexec@crop] ..\hydra\utils\sock\sock.c (270): unable to connect from "crop" to "crop" (No error)
read from stdin failed, error 9.
[mpiexec@crop] ..\hydra\tools\demux\demux_select.c (78): select error (No such file or directory)
[mpiexec@crop] ..\hydra\pm\pmiserv\pmiserv_pmci.c (501): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@crop] ..\hydra\ui\mpich\mpiexec.c (1059): process manager error waiting for completion
```

What do they mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you use Intel MPI Library for Windows. Correct?
If so, make sure you have started the process manager service (Hydra or SMPD) - refer to the User's Guide for details how to start them.